# What is the term for someone who has a last name that can also be a first name?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the term for someone who has a last name that can also be a first name? For example, *Brian Stella*.

Comment: Are you sure there _is_ such a term? (Do you recall hearing it some time ago, and now you can't remember what it is? Or are you asking on a whim?)

Comment: I have a friend like this and we usually say, "And here's a guy with two first names."

Comment: It's not the people with two first names you have to worry about. Three first names, that's a when you need to start worrying. Lee Harvey Oswald, I'm looking at you.

Comment: @MattЭллен  Three first names? Like Jay McInerney?

Comment: @MarkBeadles. I didn't get the one about Jay McInerney, but surely another example could be the actor Robert Sean Leonard, whose real name is Robert Lawrence Leonard.

Comment: I did hear of this term some time ago and I have forgotten it and it is driving me crazy that I cannot remember it!  Thanks for the comments.

Comment: @MattЭллен Pronounced "Jay, Mack, an' Ernie" :P

Comment: @MarkBeadles Oh! lol I see.

Comment: Loving the debate going in here. Really didn't expect to find this when i did a search for this phrase

Comment: Are you looking for a word (or expression; really don't limit yourself to a single word) for the _person_ who has the name, or the name itself, and if the latter, is it the full name you want to have a word for or just the family name that can also be used as a given name? Or do you want a word for the _practice_ of doing this? Whatever the question, there doesn't seem to be an answer for any of them. But see the related [Surnames made first names](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45978/are-all-english-surnames-made-first-names-masculine) question.

Comment: Mr. This-could-be-my-first-name

Answer (score 6):

No such word exists, because it would be entirely redundant.  *Any* surname can be turned into a forename, on the whim of the parents.

Comment: That's a good point. Moreover, that practice is not exactly rare, especially with middle names (at least in the U.S., it's not unheard of to use the mother's maiden name as the child's middle name). But I assumed the O.P. was referring to common names. Perhaps a more interesting phenomenon is when the last name is a common first name, and the first name is a common last name: e.g., Thomas Scott (or Scott Thomas).

Comment: Not an answer to the question, hence the downvote.  Would suggest deleting this.

Comment: It may not be a direct answer, but it does address the scope of the question. (Perhaps this would have made a better comment than an answer, but I don't think it needs to be deleted.)

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I've edited the answer to make it answer the question more directly.

Comment: @Christi: a perfectly good answer is to state that the question does not have an answer.

Comment: But that's just wrong.  Surely it is fairly apparent that a "Lucas Allen" or a "Henry William" is a different sort of name than "Winthorp Honeybucket," or even "Washington Irving."

Comment: @Dmitri If the questioner had asked: *What is the term for someone whose last name is also a common first name?* then you would have a valid point.  But the question was: *What is the term for someone who has a last name that can also be a first name?*  Do you see the difference?

Comment: @Pitarou : My general rule on language, the smaller the word, the more shades of meaning it can have.  The word "can" is an excellent case in point: I had no trouble understanding that in this question "can also be a first name," doesn't  mean "function as" but rather "is commonly accepted as."  In fact, this usage is so common, that I fear that both your answer and your impassioned defense are beginning to have a whiff of pedantry about them.

Comment: @Dmitri I take your point.  And the questioner's example (*Brian Stella*) falls in the category of last names that commonly function as first names.

Answer (score 5):

I've always heard this called a "reversible name" - but that's referring to the forename and surname together.

Here is a list of them.  http://richard.tangle-wood.co.uk/reverse.html

Comment: You antipodeans can sure coin a nickname.  "Reversible name" is almost as good as "two dads" for someone with a double last name, like the John Rhys Davies that roams your New Zealand woods with his dwarven axe. I've never heard it here, but will use it: "Hey, are you Wallace David when it rains, or is your name not fully reversible?"

Comment: Actually, @Dmitri I believe it's a British expression.  It's certainly a British web site that I provided the link for.  I'm pretty sure John Rhys Davies is British too.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure there is no specific term to describe the generic concept you're describing. The closest specific term is probably a [pseudo-surname](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surname#Surname_formed_from_a_parent.27s_name) where a child takes on a parent's first name as their last name. This is referred to as a [Patronymic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patronymic) or a [Matronymic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matronymic) name.

> **Patronym** - a family name derived from name of your father or a
>   paternal ancestor (especially with an affix (such as -son in English
>   or O'- in Irish) added to the name of your father or a paternal
>   ancestor)

Source: http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/patronym

Comment: Isn't this the opposite of what the OP asked?

Comment: JLG - No, it's not the opposite, it's an example of a last name that could also be a first name. A child takes on a last name that was the parent's first name.

Answer (score 4):

Surname Adaptation?

During the American Civil War, soldiers began to use the surnames of their commanding officers (Grant, Lee, Sherman) as first names for their sons. This, and the American custom of using the mother's maiden name as a child's given name, along with the general twentieth century trend towards 'new' names, has led to many other surnames being recognised as first names. Thus Old English and Celtic personal names, long out of use except in their adaptation as surnames, have returned to the central stock. This was formerly almost exclusively confined to boys' names but is now beginning to produce many new girls' names, especially in America. The more established surname adaptations are subject to the same spelling variations as other first names. [The link](http://tekeli.li/onomastikon/England-Firstnames/Surname-Adaptations/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

I guess you could say they're *interchangeable surnames and forenames*. Here's a link with many examples: http://www.nationalfinder.com/surnames/index.htm#INTERCHANGE

Or you could also use *interchangeable surnames and given names.*

Or, as Jim said in a comment, this can be called ["having two first names."](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TwoFirstNames) There's even [a Facebook group for people with two first names](http://www.facebook.com/pages/People-With-Two-First-Names/54672994120) and an [Urban Dictionary entry](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Two%20First%20Names).

And apparently, on further Internet searching, there is the term "firsty firsty" for this. See this blog as an example: http://firstyfirsty.blogspot.com/2008/02/curse-of-firsty-firsty.html

Comment: They're only interchangeable when the forename also happens to be a surname.

Comment: @Pitarou, Why do you say that?

Comment: The original questioner wants to know about the situation where the surname works as a forename.  Names are only interchangeable when the surname works as a forename **and** the forename works as a surname.  So "interchangeable" is not the word the original questioner is looking for (although it's probably the closest match).

Comment: @Pitarou, but with two names that can be first names, isn't that always the case?

Comment: If this is hard for you to understand, imagine that a questioner asks, "What's the word for a woman who isn't married?" and someone answers, "A nun." Is that a good answer? Well, a nun isn't married, but there are plenty of unmarried women who **aren't** nuns, so "A nun." isn't the word the questioner is looking for.

Similarly, someone with interchangeable names has a surname that can also be a first name, but there are plenty of people with surnames that can be forenames who **don't** have interchangeable names, so "interchangeable names" isn't the word the questioner is looking for.

Comment: @Pitarou: I agree that _interchangeable_ probably isn't the exact right word, but I appreciated the link anyway. It's close; out of the billions of pages on the internet, that one is tantalizingly close to the OP's question. This question may not even have a real answer, but that link could be a clue pointing someone else in the right direction. As for your **nun** example, true, it's NOT the right word, yet I could see joking about an unmarried relative: "She lives like a nun," even if she wasn't Catholic! That's the beauty of language: just when you think a word is wrong, maybe it can work.

Answer (score 2):

I thought *firsty firsty* might just have been a term used by kids, but this appears to be evidence of [wider use in popular culture](http://www.gq.com/about/firsty-firsty).

Note that there is a corresponding *lasty lasty*.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the term you are looking for is *surname names*. nameberry.com and thinkbabynames.com both refer to this term in the context you ask.