# What is the term for a person with same first and last name?

Tags: terminology, names

What is it called when a person has the exact same first and last name (and same spelling), whether named by parents or as a result of marriage? For example, *Thomas Thomas*.

Comment: A stutter? A stammer? :)

Comment: Not a duplicate, but somewhat related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70728/what-is-the-term-for-someone-who-has-a-last-name-that-can-also-be-a-first-name

Comment: I would call him Ditto.

Comment: Or via an old joke, Sam Ting!

Answer (score 13):

They are very likely informally termed [tautonyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautonym) or as the Wikipedia page tells me, linguistically called [reduplicants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication). There's a [page full of people](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_people_with_reduplicated_names) with reduplicated names including:

> - José José
> - Justo Justo
> - Kelly Kelly
> - Lisa Lisa
> - Thomas T. Thomas

The term is not used solely for names with reduplicated first and last names, but also for other variants such as *Jar Jar Binks* or *Richie Rich*.

Comment: Good to hear this word!