# What is the term for using an ancestral given name as a surname?

Tags: surnames

This is NOT a question about people who have surnames that are usually found as given names, such as Rand Paul.

My question relates to the process of Americanization of surnames. For example, I have done genealogical research about descendants of Harry Krewiansky who took the surnames Harris and Harrison, and descendants of Bernard Gogolinsky who took the surname Barney.

Comment: Why in the world would this have a “term” for it? You simply describe it, and you are done.

Comment: I take issue with "Americanization" in this context; this process has been happening worldwide, for hundreds of years - certainly since the widespread European adoption of surnames and possibly even longer elsewhere.  In Scandinavian-derived names there's the suffix _-son_ / _-ssen_; in Russian there's the suffix _-ov_; in Ukrainian _-enko_; in Armenian _-ian_ / _-yan_; there are surely other patterns I'm forgetting.

Comment: Armenian tradition is a little unusual in that the same suffix is used both for patronymic and geographic names; *Grigoryan* is a guy whose ancestor was named Grigor, while *Alepyan* is a guy whose family came from Aleppo.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the term for someone who has a last name that can also be a first name?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70728/what-is-the-term-for-someone-who-has-a-last-name-that-can-also-be-a-first-name) Specifically, [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/84500/2637)

Answer (score 2):

**[Patronymic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/patronymic)**:

> a name derived from that of the father or a paternal ancestor usually by the addition of an affix

Also from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patronymic):

> A patronym, or patronymic, is a component of a personal name based on the **given name** of one's father, grandfather or an even earlier male ancestor.

---

**[Matronymic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/matronymic)**:

> a name derived from that of the mother or a maternal ancestor

Also from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matronymic):

> A matronymic is a personal name based on the name of one's mother, grandmother, or any female ancestor. It is the female equivalent of a patronymic.

---

For second part of the question, we may call the process as "**Anglicisation of Patronymic names**" or "**Anglicisation of Matronymic names**".