# Term for someone who has a last name that can also be a first name

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

There *is* such a term but I can't remember it. We learned it in Junior High. A co-worker of mine can't remember it either, but she thinks it begins with *para-*, which helps me none.

Comment: This has been asked before but no answer was marked as accepted: see http://english.stackexchange.com/q/70728/8609

Comment: Like _Major Major Major Major_?